# IllegalArgumentException without any http reuest

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https, tomcat8

Seeing below error in `catalina.log` few minutes after starting `tomcat 8.5.47 version` .

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:490)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:682)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note: Gone through many solution provided in internet , but all says about explicit http request made causing the issue but in my case issue is happening just after starting the server without any explicit http request.

Comment: what is the uri you are using?

Comment: @pradosh nair No uri used. Just started the server with my application and got the error after few minutes . I am using java.net.InetAddress to get localhostName() .Suspecting if its making a http call internally which is causing the issue. But not sure .

Answer (score 1):

Something must be talking to your server to make that happen, but whatever it is doesn't appear to be a conformant HTTP client.

My suggestion is to use Wireshark or something similar to try to capture the the packets that the server is receiving that are triggering the message.  Figure out what is in the packets and where they are coming from.

Once you have some information about what this traffic is and where it is coming from, you will be a step closer to a solution.

Comment: I have checked localhost-access log for all the incoming request during the time we received the error, also tried manually triggering similar request but couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: If there is a malformed request, it probably won't be logged in the access log.  That's why I suggested using a packet logger.

Comment: Thanks you suggestion really helped and used localhost-access log to findout the exact uri making the request. From that found the source ip address and after doing nslookup got the hostname and able figure out the culprit.Thanks a lot Stephen.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see, the error occurs in the `parseRequestLine` method. Somebody (hopefully, you) is sending an invalid HTTP request to your server.

Generally, connecting clients sending you baloney requests should just be ignored and not logged, or at least, if you're going to log any of it, certainly not the stack trace which doesn't accomplish much; you'd want to log the IP and some details about the nature of the request they sent.

I'm not sure if you're catching this exception and printing this, or if catalina is, but, either way, this log should just be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot for your respionse. But No uri used. Just started the server with my application and got the error after few minutes . I am using java.net.InetAddress to get localhostName() .Suspecting if its making a http call internally which is causing the issue. But not sure .